# meaning of django migrate ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, django

https://tryhackme.com/room/django

I am trying to follow the above django tutorial.

```
django-admin startproject mysite
cd mysite
python3 manage.py migrate
python3 manage.py startapp Articles
```

The directory structure looks like this.

```
$ tree
.
├── Articles
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   └── views.py
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
└── mysite
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __pycache__
    │   ├── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
    │   ├── settings.cpython-37.pyc
    │   └── urls.cpython-37.pyc
    ├── settings.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── wsgi.py

4 directories, 16 files
```

In `mysite/settings.py`, I modified the following line.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'Articles', # add
    'django.contrib.admin',
...
```

In `mysite/urls.py`, I changed the following lines.

```
from django.urls import path, include # modified

urlpatterns = [
    path('Articles/', include('Articles.urls')), # added
```

But when I run the following command, it fails. Does anybody know what is wrong? Thanks.

```
$ python3 manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 361, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 65, in _run_checks
    issues.extend(super()._run_checks(**kwargs))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 377, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 40, in check_url_namespaces_unique
    all_namespaces = _load_all_namespaces(resolver)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 57, in _load_all_namespaces
    url_patterns = getattr(resolver, 'url_patterns', [])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 584, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 577, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/private/tmp/mktemp/tmp.xwK721S20r/mysite/mysite/urls.py", line 20, in <module>
    path('Articles/', include('Articles.urls')),
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Articles.urls'
```

Comment: can you add the output of the directlry structure of your project?

Comment: There is no urls.py module under Articles directory.

Comment: Of course! Good catch! However, as a personal rule, I NEVER use anything else that all lowercase modules names, sometimes an underscore in it, at worse.

Answer (score 0):

Add urls.py in your article directory
and in your urls.py file add these lines

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('urlPathName', views.nameOfFucntionView, name="referenceNameForTemplateUsAGE"),
    
]
```

For the sack of this demonstration, i have given an example of views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
    def nameOfFucntionView(request):
        return render(request, 'Article/someFile.html')
```

and in your setting.py
add these lines

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
      "Articles.apps.ArticlesConfig",
...
```